# Convert date time string from C# to date object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a cookie in C# and sending the object to the client via SignalR:

```
      public void Send(string name, string message,string connId)
    {
        var cookie = GetAuthCookie(connId);
        Clients.Client(connId).addNewMessageToPage(name, message,cookie);
    }

    public static HttpCookie GetAuthCookie(string cId)
    {
            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie("Some Cookie", "I aint goin nowhere");
            authCookie.Domain = "localhost";
            authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5000);
            return authCookie;
    }
```

The SignalR method is this:

```
 var chat = $.connection.letsChatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message, cookie) {
            // Add the message to the page.
        };
```

The date inside the cookie object is in this format:

```
   cookie.Expires = "2018-04-26T15:25:52.4197877-05:00"
```

I tried to convert that string to a date like so:

```
 var date_test = new Date("2018-04-26T15:25:52.4197877-05:00".replace(/-/g, "/"));
    alert(date_test);
```

It does not work. How do i convert that date string to a javascript date object so i can get the date and time? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, it will display a popup dialog:

Remove the `replace` and just try like this;

```js
 var date_test = new Date("2018-04-26T15:25:52.4197877-05:00".replace(/T/g, " "));
 alert(date_test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `replace` and just try like this;

```js
    var date_test = new Date("2018-04-26T15:25:52.4197877-05:00");
    console.log(date_test.getDate());
```

Comment: Thanks...i see you implemented the kiss method :)